# Add contacts App for Multiple Google Account

Tags: gmail, google-contacts-api

I have 5 google accounts which we use for work purpose, in that one google account we have to save all the contacts where we can reuse of it.

I am thinking of creating a Google Script App to add contacts. But my question is, does this allow to do it since I am using other google account in the same machine Or can I login only to contacts from other browser and it should not allow to download any information from the cloud.

Is there any such provisions or work around?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [forum](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-share-and-sync-contacts-between-different-Google-Apps-domains) on how to sync contacts from multiple Google accounts. There are several third party apps which you can use to transfer contacts from one Google Apps domain to the other. This [blog](https://www.refractiv.co.uk/news/create-global-shared-contacts-google-apps-via-spreadsheet-sync/) might also help.